# C# Reading from XML file using pattern

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <SaleGroupsFiles>
  <SaleGroup id="1" active="true" name="US"> 
   <files
      location="c:\mypath\"
      fileType="pdf"
      destination1="outputpath1">
      destination2="outputpath2">
    </files>
  </SaleGroup>

  <SaleGroup id="2" active="true" name="Canada"> 
  <files
      location="c:\mypath\"
      fileType="pdf"
      destination1="outputpath1">
      destination2="outputpath2">
      destination3="outputpath3">
    </files>
  </SaleGroup>
</SaleGroupFiles>
```

Note that there are could be variable number of destinations. The rest is fixed.
I am trying to read the data in one shot using XDocument

```
public class SaleGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SaleFile File { get; set; }
}

public class SaleFile
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string[] Destination { get; set; }
}

static List<string> GetSettings(string path)
{
    var document = XDocument.Load(path);
    var root = document.Root;
    var results =
        root
        .Descendants("SaleGroup")
        .Select(element => new SaleGroup()
        {
            Active = Convert.ToBoolean(element.Attribute("active").Value),
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(element.Attribute("id").Value),
            Name = element.Attribute("name").Value,
            File = new SaleFile()
            {
                FileType = element.Descendants("files").Single().Attribute("fileType").Value,
                Location = element.Descendants("files").Single().Attribute("location").Value
            }
        })
        .ToList();
```

It reads everything, except destinations. Is there a way to include loading of all destinations (destination1, destination2...) into an array or a List (using Like or regex or something else)? Or I need to abandon this approach and just read all values in a loop?

Comment: If you have control over the xml, I would strongly recommend reworking this. Your destinations should be child nodes, not attributes.

Comment: I don't think this can be done in one shot if the number of destination attributes is variable. That's an awful design. I strongly agree that the destinations should be nodes.

Comment: If changing the xml is not an option, you can always get a list of attributes that start with the desired string: `Destination = document.Descendants("files").Single().Attributes().Where(a => a.Name.ToString().StartsWith("destination")).Select(a => a.Value);`. For the record, in my opinion it's messy, prone to errors and I dislike "one shot" techniques, specially when performance is not a concern. It's usually a nightmare to debug.